# When in Fullscreen OSX Yosemite won't show the dock if "auto-hide-dock" is enabled.

Tags: macos, dock, fullscreen

While my dock "auto-hide" is enabled when, in full-screen app, if I put the pointer to the very bottom, the dock won't show up.
Unless, and this might be a bug, I move my mouse horizontally and it reaches and already opened app. Sounds weird but I don't understand

Comment: It isn't supposed to.

Answer (score 5):

I was a bit stumped by this, but actually I think there is an explicit procedure.

When in full-screen mode, move the cursor to the bottom of the screen; then drag down with one finger. The dock will then appear.

It appears it doesn't matter where you do this (which application icon you happen to hovering over) as far as I can see.

Comment: More specifically, with a trackpad it looks like what counts is holding the finger down a bit longer. i.e. quickly dragging down a thousands times does nothing but moving it down slowly and holding the finger there does it.

Comment: Just move the mouse pointer to the bottom of the screen little slower than you move normally (where dock is hidden) to make it appear while in fullscreen.

Or move mouse pointer to the bottom, and wait for a while until dock appears while holding the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be also with the speed you use. If you move the mouse slower, when it reaches the bottom the dock will show up. I think is intentional, but I don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too.
I tried moving the mouse down to the bottom of the screen and then pulling down again and that worked. Don't ask me why it has to be this complicated, I think its a bug. 
Hope This is Helpful

Comment: I think it's intentional. It's not complicated, you simply need to move the mouse further down when it's at the bottom of the screen. I don't think it's unnatural for the Dock to behave differently in fullscreen.

Comment: as bfred.it says above, just hold your finger on the trackpad a split second after your cursor moves to the bottom.   No need for a separate gesture.